# Webpack CSS class non applied to HTML elements and React components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I set up a project with Webpack, Lit2 and React.

I have a problem with CSS Stylesheet and React components. I created a stylesheet 'homesheet.module.css' and imported in my React component.

```
import styles from '../homesheet.module.css';

export const CustomDivider = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <hr className={styles.customDivider}></hr>
    </>
  );
};
```

My Webpack configs are:

```
// For our css modules these will be locally scoped
const CSSModuleLoader = {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: {
      localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
    },
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: false, // turned off as causes delay
  }
}
// For our normal CSS files we would like them globally scoped
const CSSLoader = {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: false, // turned off as causes delay
  }
}

// Standard style loader (prod and dev covered here)
const styleLoader = devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './index-app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
        use: [styleLoader, CSSLoader]
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.css$/,
        use: [styleLoader, CSSModuleLoader]
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    clean: true,
  },
};
```

If i build the project, go to the page I'm interested in with any browser and open the inspector, I see my

---

element with a class name assigned, but the style is not applied and the class is not shown on the Style tab of the inspector.

[hr from the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFNU5.png)

[hr styles from the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBUJ9.png)

I don't have any console error.
Can you help me to figure it out? I checked everywhere.

I tried to change webpack configs file, I installed the css-loader and style-loader. I also tried to use and import the css sheet without module but nothing worked.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Can you please post the CSS rule which is targeting your `hr` element? From what I can tell by looking at your [hr from inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFNU5.png) image, your `hr` element doesn't have a `customDivider` class. Rather, it has a `homesheet-module_customDivder__nXTy` class.